# Convert unix time/utc to a specific timezone

Tags: java, jodatime

I have the current milliseconds utc/unix time and now I want to convert this to a datetime for a specific timezone e.g. EST UTC -5 (new york).

I get the current milliseconds/ unix time using:

```
System.currentTimeMillis
```

Now I want to convert this long value to a specific timezone.

How can I do this with Joda time as I have heard this is the best library to use but the API seems a bit confusing to me.

Comment: In general you don't convert the time, you leave the time as GMT+0 and to use the local timezone when you print it. i.e. it is only when you convert it to a String does it apply.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I was thinking of storing unix time in the db, i.e. how many seconds since 1970.  Then at the UI level convert it to a timezone.  Isn't this a fine way to do it?

Comment: That is how it is normally done. Though you can store the number of milli-seconds.

Comment: JSR 310 is a replacement for the old Java Calendar and JodaTime and is built in to Java 8.  Use that if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime(long)](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28long%29) followed by [DateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone)](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29). Something like

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(millis).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Somewhere");
```

Comment: I was looking to use Jodatime.

Comment: It IS DateTime class from Joda. Have you checked hyperlinks?

Comment: Sorry I assumed that was a java.util.Date, thanks looking into it.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

> I get the current milliseconds/ unix time using: `System.currentTimeMillis`

Do not do this.

The `Instant.now()` method replaces that outmoded method. Furthermore, `Instant` is capable of finer granularity, up to nanoseconds. Currently the implementation in OpenJDK captures the current moment in microseconds, much finer than that other method’s milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2019-07-27T02:15:34.727766Z
>
> Now I want to convert this long value to a specific timezone.

Specify your time zone as a `ZoneId`. Apply to the `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;  // Or did you have another zone in mind, such as `America/Montreal` ?
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Or, you can skip the `Instant`. Call `ZonedDateTime.now` while passing a `ZoneId`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

> a specific timezone e.g. EST UTC -5 (new york).

EST is *not* a true time zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

> How can I do this with Joda time as I have heard this is the best library to use but the API seems a bit confusing to me.

The *Joda-Time* project is now succeeded by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later as defined by JSR 310. Android 26 and later has these classes too.

- Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.
- Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

You comment about writing to database. If your database has proper date-time types, use them rather than storing a long integer.

As of JDBC 4.2 we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

A moment such as we have discussed here should be stored in a column of a data type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (`WITH`, *not* `WITHOUT`!).

Oddly, the JDBC spec requires support only for `OffsetDateTime` rather than `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`. So, convert.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;    // Adjust to a time zone.
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;                 // Adjust to UTC.
```

What is the difference between `OffsetDateTime` & `ZonedDateTime`?

- An offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds. Nothing more.
- A time zone is *much* more. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

[image]